# Resources for Salesforce Touch development

Tags: app-development, touch

I am learning to create apps with Salesforce Touch, can anyone recommend any resources to help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Salesforce_touch_platform .Go through this article also you can download a book recently launched by salesforce .This is helpful if you are planning to develop your app from scratch using force.com platform

Also if you are using salesforce Licenced touch not developing on your own use the following link to explore more

http://www.salesforce.com/docs/en/touch_faq_tablet/touch_faq_tablet_accessing.htm